# Multithreading with pyqt5

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, qt-designer, pypdf

I am creating an app "pdf text to speech" and it works fine.

[image]

When I press "convert" I want this group box to run in a separate thread displaying the progress (the progress bar is inside a group box) and the current page. How can I do this?
This is the function I am using to convert text to speech:

```
def convert_clicked(self):
    self.start = int(self.lineEdit_5.text()) #start reading
    self.end = int(self.lineEdit_8.text())
    speaker = pyttsx3.init()
    speaker.setProperty("rate", 140)
    for i in range(self.start-1, self.end+1):
            page = self.pdfreader.getPage(i)
            text = page.extractText()
            speaker.runAndWait()
            speaker.save_to_file(text, f'{self.save_path}\\page {i+1}.mp3')
    self.book.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example with Pyqt5, using pyqt5 threads. I've included a signal you can emit back to your main application so you can update the progress bar as well as an int example (emit_var), to show how you can pass data from your main thread to the worker thread. I usually put the thread at the top of my code above the QMainApplication and the initialization and listen function below.

```
Class multi_thread_name(QtCore.QThread):
     signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

     def init(self, message):

         QtCore.QThread.init(self)

         self.message = message

         def run(self):

            print(self.message)

            print("insert your code here to be executed in the 
            thread")


            for i in range(0,100):
                emit_var = i

        
                self.signal.emit(emit_var)
```

To get the signal data transmitted from the thread you need a listener thread.

```
def listen(message):

    print("message will be an int, emitted from the pyqt thread for 
    your progress bar. Put in your progress bar object to set val")

    self.progress_bar.setValue(message)

def initilize_thread():

    var_to_pass = "string your passing through to the thread if you 
    want to send data to the thread")

    self.thread = multi_thread_name(var_to_pass)
    self.thread.start()
    self.thread.signal.connect(listen)

self.convert_button.clicked.connect(initilize_thread)
```

Comment: `listen()` and `initialize_thread()` are inside the class right?

Comment: No so where you have your Class UI_MainWindow(object)  def setupUI(self, MainWindow) for you Main application, you place the listen and initilize thread function below that code after your retranslateUI(self,MainWindow) code . So when you have a button you can connect it to the initilize_thread. So thread goes just below your inputs, and the other two functions go below your application code just above if__name__ == "__main__" code.

Comment: Great! Just one more thing. where should i place my `convert_clicked()` method? I mean I tried to make a connection between this method and your code, but the progress bar still not working!

Comment: You add this below your initializer thread.  i've added an example to illustrate to the answer, when you get it working pls upvote answer :) bare in mind you also need to update your progress bar with the emitted message from the thread. have also added this

Comment: Please fix the code, as it has *a lot* of issues (bad indentation, wrong method names, missing arguments). Also, don't suggest to edit pyuic generated files, as it's a bad practice that always leads to confusion and unexpected behavior.

Comment: Edited the indentation that's my mistake. As for the wrong method names, missing arguments, none of those are present, i just copied and pasted code i ran before posting the answer, it all compiles and runs successfully. As for suggesting editing puic generated files, i didn't. That file you are meant to copy into another file and then edit around it otherwise what is the point of designer and pyuic for UI design. The only problem with editing the py generated file is that you may overwrite that file if you use the pyuic command again after ui changes. There's nothing inherently wrong with it